# How do I know how many items were cleared with the clear command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I have a command block and use the clear command, there is a way to know the amount of items were cleared?

For example, the command:

```
clear theplayer minecraft:stone
```

How do I know how much stone was cleared?

Comment: Try putting a comparator next to the command block, and see if it changes signal strength at all. If it does, then you need to figure out what signal levels correspond to what amount of items. If it does nothing, then I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Since the clear command can clear away hundreds of amounts of items I'd expect that comparator approach to fail. Redstone only has 16 strengths, so at best you're getting a very vague figure.

Comment: With the next update you'll be able to clear items one by one.  You could set up a counter to count how many times a clear succeeds, but that would be time consuming and require a potentially large counter, plus a large decoder.  Or better, you could store it to a scoreboard stat.

Answer (score 1):

It should say Cleared the inventory of player, removing x items.  You can also do /clear player item 0  for a specific amount.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to get the number removed to be used in another command.

Comment: Ok... well, I guess you could /clear stone item 0 x, and then have that go into another command block connected through a comparator and have that do a command with the same x. What exactly are you trying to do overall? I might be able help more if I knew what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Most commands have return values. In the case of `/clear` it's the number of items that were cleared, which is exactly what you want. Now the next question: How to use this value? In 1.12 it was complicated, you needed `/stats` and know who or what executed the command, you needed to prepare some things, etc. Now in 1.13 it's much easier:

```
/execute store result score @s <score> run clear <selector>
```

Here `<score>` is the name of a scoreboard where you want to store the number in and `<selector>` is the player name or selector of which you want to clear the inventory (or items of a type). You can also directly store it in NBT or a bossbar by using something else than `score`. More information in the [wiki article about `/execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/execute&oldid=1288315)).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat alike to what DJDavid said.  If you have it set up to a clock you can have a Comaparator going out of it adding onto a Scoreboard 1.

Example I have a clock set up to run the command "/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:arrow"}]}" connected to a Command block that runs two commands.  The first being "/clear @p stone" and the second "scoreboard players @p (Obj. Name) 1"

But this will only work my clearing one stone at a time if the player received more than one stone, for instance he received 5 stone from a chest or a furnace the Machine would only calculate it as 1 stone.  As the Machine cleared all stone from the player's inventory and only only having one pulse outputting to the second command.

If that is too confusing let me know.